# QDomElement.setAttribute crashes program

Tags: c++, qt, dom, qt5

It's confusing. My program was working reliably. Then, I did some changes in a hurry, they didn't work, re-winded them, went to show my program and it no longer works. My fault for not making new copy every 10min. The thing is however, the program crashes in a place which makes no sense.

```
QDomElement Expense::toNode()
{
    QDomElement e=Entry::toNode(); //Entry is parent of Expense
    QString temp;
    //std::string getThis=e.nodeName().toStdString();
    temp=QString::fromStdString(Category); //Category is string field

    //e.hasAttribute("category"); //this works
    //e.setAttribute("ha","hi"); //this crashes program
    //e.setAttribute("category",temp); //this also crashes program
    return e;
}
```

I thought that maybe in hurry I modified some library, but if I create a new `QDomElement`, and edit it's attributes, there is no problem at all. Then I thought that maybe my node is not a node at all, but I can use many other functions (like for example `e.hasAttribute`). Is there limit to amount of attributes we can set? What might be the error?

In case it helps:

```
QDomElement Entry::toNode()
{
    QDomDocument d("EzXpns");
    QDomElement e=d.createElement("entry");
    QString temp;
    temp=QString::fromStdString(Name);
    e.setAttribute("name",temp);
    temp=QString::fromStdString(to_string(static_cast<long double>(Amount)));
    e.setAttribute("amount",temp);
    temp=QString::fromStdString(to_string(static_cast<long long>(Date[0])));
    e.setAttribute("dateyear",temp);
    temp=QString::fromStdString(to_string(static_cast<long long>(Date[1])));
    e.setAttribute("datemonth",temp);
    temp=QString::fromStdString(to_string(static_cast<long long>(Date[2])));
    e.setAttribute("dateday",temp);
    temp=QString::fromStdString(Comment);
    e.setAttribute("comment",temp);
    return e;
}
```

Edit: I should have specified, that if I try to debug this is the message I get:

> TestBuild.exe has triggered a breakpoint

then

> Unhandled exception at 0x77d415de in TestBuild.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x13fb8ff8.

then

> 0x77d3016e in TestBuild.exe: 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully.

Edit2: Sample xml

```
<!DOCTYPE data>
<EzXpns>
  <account>
    <login name="b" password="1"/>
    <expHis>
      <entry comment="9" dateday="1" name="k" dateyear="0" amount="9" datemonth="1"/>
      <entry comment="9" dateday="1" name="b" dateyear="0" amount="9" datemonth="1"/>
      <entry comment="9" dateday="1" name="b" dateyear="0" amount="9" datemonth="1"/>
      <entry comment="9" dateday="1" name="b" dateyear="0" amount="9" datemonth="1"/>
      <entry comment="9" dateday="1" name="b" dateyear="0" amount="9" datemonth="1"/>
    </expHis>
    <incomeHis/>
  </account>
</EzXpns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was within the Qt documentation.

Look at how I create new element, I do it by calling `QDomDocument d("EzXpns");` , which is a mistake. In Qt, after the `QDomDocument` is destroyed SO ARE ALL CHILD NODES. It worked before just because of pure luck. Creating one `QDomDocument`, and then passing it around, solved my problem.